# IF statement with 3 variables and show blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

0

Cell A1 can be filled in with whole number values

I want that if Cell A1 is less than 10 then B1 says'<10' I want that if Cell A1 is between 10 and 25 then B1 says'10-25' I want that if Cell A1 is more than 25 then B1 says'>25' however if A1 is blank then B1 should also be blank

I have the formula working to show the correct value however I cannot get B1 to show blank if A1 is blank.

I will be happy to use normal formulas or even VBA for this to work.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -
Cell B1 formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",IF(A1<10,"<10",IF(AND(A1>=10,A1<=25),"10-25","")))
```

To also show "25+" when A1 > 25, use this instead.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",IF(A1<10,"<10",IF(AND(A1>=10,A1<=25),"10-25",IF(A1>25,"25+",""))))
```

Answer (score 7):

How about this formula?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"<10","10-25",">25"},MATCH(A1,{1,10,25})),"")
```

The above formula will show a blank for numbers <1. If you need to evaluate such numbers as "<10" start the MATCH() array at 0 instead of 1.

Comment: Clever use of `MATCH()`

Answer (score 1):

Test blank first:

```
=IF(A1="","",IF(A1<10,"<10",IF(A1>25,">25","10-25")))
```

Answer (score 1):

for vba you could try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set Target = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1"))

If Not Target Is Nothing Then 'if action is not NOT happening in A1, do something...
    Select Case Range("A1")
        Case "": ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Clear
        Case Is < 10: ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "<10"
        Case Is < 25: ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "10-25"
        Case Else: ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = ">25"
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```